# slidedown is not working in the way intended

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am very much new to html, jquery and css .I am trying to create a navigation bar and when i will click on that navigation bar it will open a jquery slidedown but it is not working in the way intended. Below is a small portion of the code that i have written for this purpose

```
      html: 
            <ul class="dropdown">
        <li id="cl1"><a class="ab" href="#">About </a></li >
            </ul>
      css:
            <div class="target" style="z-    
                  index:3;width:1000px;height:1000px;display:none;background-    
                  color:white;opacity:0.8;position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;">                                   
             <img src="horse.jpg" alt="horse" />
            </div>
      jquery:
                $(document).ready(function() {

               $(".ab").click(function(){
                  $(".target").slideDown( 'slow', function());
                });
               });


            there are more sub menus to the above html
```

Answer (score 0):

you have syntax error in this line

```
$(".target").slideDown( 'slow', function());
```

it should be

```
$(".target").slideDown( 'slow', function(){});
```

here is a full version

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".ab").click(function(event){
            $(".target").slideDown( 'slow', function(){
            // after animation code here
            });     
            return false; //this for preventing the default event of you can use event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

Comment: You forgot to add the quotes in function as well... you have written the same thing twice :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".ab").click(function(){
    $(".target").slideDown( 'slow', function(){});
});
```

You forgot to add the quotes {} in function